# pdt script won't select from db

Tags: php, database, paypal, eclipse-pdt

I have product name and want to select download path. According to it, I get an error

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...

It's like there is no such entry.

```
<?php
$keyarray=array('num_cart_items'=>2, 'item_name2'=>'5', 'item_name1'=>'6' );
$itemname='';
for ($i=1; $i<= $keyarray['num_cart_items'] ;$i++){
        $itemname[]= $keyarray['item_name'.$i];};

    foreach($itemname as & $var){  
    echo $var; 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name='$var' ");
    $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    $checkout_path ="";
    if ($productCount > 0) {

        // get path
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
                 $path = $row["path"];
                 $checkout_path[]=array('path'=>$path);

          echo $checkout_path;
       }
    }
    //echo  $checkout_path;
?>
```

Comment: What's the value of `$var`? If there are any bad characters (such as the single quote), it will break your query! You really should be using MySQLi/PDO so you can prepare this.

Comment: Is this the entire script? I can't see the connection string to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

look first if you have an error after you run the query

```
echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() . "\n";
```

also about the results, you may have more than one result so you need to make foreach loop to grt all of them like :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

}
```

another note prevent using **`mysql_*`** functions because:

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the script you have declared `$itemname='';` as a string
and then later on used it as an array `$itemname[]= $keyarray['item_name'.$i];};`.

Use `$itemname=array();` to delare it as an array.

And use either `PDO` or `mysqli`, as `mysql` is deprecated and is not supported in the later versions